# Python pywhatkit emoticon

Tags: python, whatsapp, emoticons

I'm using pywhatkit library for sending message to whatsapp, and it works fine, but I need to send emoticon and the text splitted in more line.

Is possible to send new line and emoticon?

I've tried with the following code:

```
msg = 'text :-) \n new line :-)'
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(NUMBER, str(msg) , 5, False, 5)
```

but it not works, and I received the exactly string (not emoticon and new line) that I've worte

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can write `msg` variable like this to send the message in next line
And to get the emoticons you can use hex codes like this: `\U0001F600` (Reference: [Emoticon](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-include-emojis-in-your-python-code/#:%7E:text=Using%20Unicode%20Characters%20to%20Print%20Emoji&text=When%20using%20Unicode%20with%20Python,is%20prefixed%20with%20the%20Unicode.)) -

```
msg = '''text \U0001F600 \n 

new line

\U0001F600 '''
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, new line is ok and it works, but not emoticon I receive :-)

Comment: I have corrected the code, use this to add emoticon.

Comment: it works also if msg='''msg\nmsg1 \U0001F600'''. Another question, but if I've a variable str1='msg\nmsg1 \U0001F600', how to concatenate it in msg? for example msg='''{str1}''' (this not works)

Comment: Okay, you can directly write msg = msg+str1, this should solve your issue.

Comment: msg = msg+str1 it works, the problem is that str1 is take from configuration file (str1 = self.config.get_value_from_conf('message')) where message is "MESSAGE=Hi @@@, msg\nmsg1 \U0001F600" and msg=msg+str1 not works (emoticon and new line not show in whatsapp message).

Comment: I've seen, that it works fine, only if msg is cabled into code msg='msg\nmsg1 \U0001F600', if I put this string into my configuration.ini, it not works anymore, probably there is a string conversion

Comment: I'm not fully able to able understand your issue, but what you can try is after reading the config.ini file, see what you're getting in the variable. Is there any change in string on reading it.
or try this: str1 = str( self.config.get_value_from_conf('message')) )

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code:

```
msg = str(self.config.get_value_from_conf('message'))
print(type(msg))
msg = str(re.sub('@@@', name, msg))
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(str(number), str(msg) , 5, False, 5)
```

print type is:

```
<class 'str'>
```